# Difference between HtmlTable and TagBuilder("table")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Just wondering what the difference is between these two and what the benefit for one or the other of them would be when I build my table in my HtmlHelper

```
HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
```

and:

```
TagBuilder table = new TagBuilder("table");
```

This is more or less the same as this question,

[Why use TagBuilder instead of StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043654/why-use-tagbuilder-instead-of-stringbuilder)

but I'm wondering more specifically about the difference between these two .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that `HtmlTable` provides typed and correctly named properties for all the valid HTML attributes of the `<table>` element (e.g. `Width`, `Height`, `CellSpacing`, etc).  It also has the `Rows` property which is a typed collection of `HtmlTableRow` objects which each reresent a `<tr>` element.

`TagBuilder` is a much more generic API which could certainly be used to construct an HTML `<table>` but you'd need to do more work in a less type safe and less easy to read way.

One concrete example where `HmlTable` helps in a way that `TagBuilder` does not is in the setting of the `width=""` attribute on the `<table>` element.

With `HtmlTable`:

```
HtmlTable htmlTable = new HtmlTable();
htmlTable.Width = "100px";
```

With `TagBuilder`:

```
TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("table");
tagBuilder.Attributes["width"] = "100px";
```

Note that with `TagBuilder` both the name of the element, `table`, and the name of the attribute, `width`, are strings which introduce two opportunities for error (misspellings) that do not occur when using `HtmlTable`.

Comment: Cool. That's really what I wanted to hear. Thanks!