# Difference between HtmlGenericControl and TagBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is more or less the same as this question,
[Difference between HtmlTable and TagBuilder("table")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043800/difference-between-htmltable-and-tagbuildertable) and
[Why use TagBuilder instead of StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043654/why-use-tagbuilder-instead-of-stringbuilder)

but I want to know that we when you do not have a .Net class for an HTML tag (like iFrame) in System.Web.UI.WebControls and System.Web.UI.HtmlControls then what to use?

@Edit: Can somebody tell me the difference between TagBuilder and HtmlGenericControl ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) to represent any element:

```
HtmlGenericControl iframe = new HtmlGenericControl("iframe");
iframe.Attributes["src"] = "http://guffa.com/";
```

#### Edit:

The main difference between a `HtmlGenericControl` and the `TagBuilder` is that the control is made to work in a control hieararchy that you use to build the page, while the tag builder is only used to create the HTML code for a single tag. The control can for example have child controls, while you add child tags in a tag builder by first rendering them as strings and put them in the `InnerHtml` property.

Comment: But can t you use `TagBuilder` in exactly the same way?

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Yes, you can use the `TagBuilder` to get the same result.